# starting multiple programs at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to start a java programm and a echo command at once in my shell script, first I tried this

```
java -jar server.jar & echo "$!" > $pidfile
```

but this stopps the `server.jar` when the echo finishes, I solved this with

```
java -jar server.jar & echo "$!" > $pidfile && fg
```

It works for me but I think this isn't a clean solution.

Now I need to add another java program, and both programs should run at the same time, and the script should end if both programs are finished/stopped.
I read in another StackOverflow question that I should add a `& wait` at the end of the line, but this will stop my `server.jar`.

Actually it looks like this:

```
java -jar server.jar & echo "$!" > $pidfile && fg && java -jar heartbeat.jar
```

Edit:
The whole script and server are running in tmux, so it's not necessary to keep it alive. The `server.jar` is running around 24h and the `heartbeat.jar` check if the server is alive, both should started with one script.

**Solution:**

```
java -jar server.jar & echo "$!" > $pidfile ; java -jar heartbeat.jar & fg %1
```

I recieve both outputs from the `jars`, input command went to `server.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to explain: The reason for your Java program stopping is that all background processes will receive a `HUP` signal when the shell executing your script terminates. To prevent this, you can remove it from the list of the shell's jobs using `disown` right after the `&`.

For the two Java programs, I would suggest:

```
java -jar server.jar &          # start java with server.jar as a background job
echo "$!" > "$pidfile"          # echo the pid of the last background job into the pid file
java -jar heartbeat.jar &       # start java with heartbeat.jar as a background job
fg %1                           # set server.jar as foreground job for interactive use
```

Edit: `wait` replaced with `fg %1`, see comments.

Comment: I think the `heartbeat.jar` will only start when `server.jar` is stopped, or is it a mistake the missing `&` between `echo` and the second java program?

Comment: No. `&` just tells Bash to start the job _left_ of it in the background. The `echo` should not execute in the background, so there is no `&` after it. I will add some comments.

Comment: ok i understand, but is it possible that i can see the `server.jar` running?

Comment: You mean you need to use `server.jar` interactively?

Comment: Just add `fg %1` after starting `heartbeat.jar`. This puts that job in foreground so you can use it interactively. You probably don't even need the `wait` in that case.

Comment: this works, thanks alot.

Another cool feature of this is that I now recieve both outputs and I can send commands to the `server.jar`

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called [daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/daemon.1.html) which does put your program in background and saves pid in the file.

Also there is program that starts multiple programs at the same time called [foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/), which is great for development purposes. Its written in ruby, but there are alternatives in other languages. Java implementation [gaffer](https://github.com/jingweno/gaffer).

Comment: did you mean that I should run everything with daemon or only the `heartbeat.jar`? 
after starting the server I need an input window, so I can't use daemon for the server - for information the script is executing in tmux

Comment: Ow I didn't realize that, assume that you need to start/stop multiple programs for development, correct me if Im wrong. In that case foreman is a great tool. http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/